# LINQ - Adding record where nested value contains value from another array

Tags: c#, arrays, entity-framework, linq, tags

I'm looking to add a notification record to my users with an SQL database using Entity Framework and LINQ. My users already have a nested array of tags that they have chosen. I would like to add a notification record to a user if their chosen tags contain any tag that is included in the array tags i pass into my method.

This is what my **Tag** array looks like:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Text": "Blue",
    "Value": "blue"
  },
  {
    "Id": 4,
    "Text": "Red",
    "Value": "red"
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Text": "White",
    "Value": "white"
  }
]
```

My Notification looks like this:

```
{
    "Image": "https://www.image.com",
    "Heading": "Example heading",
    "Content": "Example content"
}
```

My users have a nested array of tags associated with them that also looks like tags array above and have the same id's.

My method is currently like this:

```
AddUserNotification(Notification notification, IList<Tag> tags) 
{
    var usersToAddTheNotificationTo = DbContext.Users
        .Where(User.Tags.Contains(tags)).ToList();

    foreach(var user in usersToAddTheNotificationTo) 
    {
          user.Notifications.Add(notification);
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this is the most simple way?

Comment: Thanks Rufus, I cant get this to work. Where does the 'user' come from?

Comment: This should be better: `.Where(user => user.Tags.Any(tag => tags.Contains(tag)))`

Comment: Ok will try that, can this method be made async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want to do is building an **intersection** between the user's tags and the notification's tags and you want to add the notification if this new intersection quantity is not empty

```
var usersToAddTheNotificationTo = DbContext.Users
        .Where(User.Tags.Intersect(tags).Count() > 0).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try this also. Can this be made async?

Comment: performing this operation async has no influence on the actual query. why would you want to perform it async?

Comment: Ok very true. What are the advantages of using 'Intersect' instead of the 'Any' approach?

Comment: 'Any' is a boolean function that tells you if a given quantity is not empty. You could also perform a 'Any()' instead of 'Count() > 0'

Comment: Thanks for the help, will run this up and see if I can get it to work

Answer (score 1):

You may run into issues associating Tags where these are not entities associated with the current context or query. Also, is the Notification a new entity, or does it represent a record that already exists in the database? Is the context expected to know about it?

When looking to associate based on criteria, I generally opt for working with IDs as this makes it simpler to query for matches. For example:

```
public void AddUserNotification(Notification notification, IList<int> tagIds) 
{
    var usersToAddTheNotificationTo = DbContext.Users
        .Where(x => x.Tags.Any(t => tagIds.Contains(t.TagId)).ToList();

    foreach(var user in usersToAddTheNotificationTo) 
    {
          user.Notifications.Add(notification);
    }
}
```

Without changing the signature:

```
public void AddUserNotification(Notification notification, IList<Tag> tags) 
{
    var tagIds = tags.Select(x => x.TagId).ToList();
    var usersToAddTheNotificationTo = DbContext.Users
        .Where(x => x.Tags.Any(t => tagIds.Contains(t.TagId)).ToList();

    foreach(var user in usersToAddTheNotificationTo) 
    {
          user.Notifications.Add(notification);
    }
}
```

One other caution: If Notification represents an existing record then you should also load it from the context based on the ID.

`var existingNotification = DbContext.Notifications.Single(x => x.NotificationId == notification.NotificationId);`

Entities passed in to things like Controller actions are deserialized, so as far as a DbContext is concerned they are no different to code like:

`var notification = new Notification { NotificationId = 16, .... };`

It doesn't matter that earlier the notification was loaded from a DbContext. It was a different DbContext instance, and the entity was serialized and deserialized. EF will treat it as a new record. If the PK is configured as an Identity, you will get a new record inserted with a new NotificationID. If the PK isn't configured, you'll get a key violation as EF attempts to insert a duplicate row. You can associate it to the DbContext using `Attach()` and set the State to "Modified" but this opens your system to a significant risk of tampering as clients could alter that entity in ways you don't expect, changing FKs or other values your UI doesn't permit and overwrite the data.